# Choosing and loading one of alternative shared libs at runtime

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Was trying to add NEON support to an application, per the CPU-ARM-NEON.html in the docs. The docs mention runtime checks, but it turns out a native library cannot be both plain-v7a and NEON at the same time anyway, the runtime linker simply won't load such a library on some devices.

So it looks like I need two versions of the same library, optimized for different capabilities, to load one at runtime manually. [Reportedly](https://moodstocks.com/blog/article/ice-cream-sandwich-why-native-code-support-sucks/) this can be done, though it is a step away from the ndk-through-eclipse path and I'm at loss on how to set things up.

I figured I list one of the versions under LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES for the core to link properly, but then whatever I list there gets added to core dependencies. Runtime linker then checks for it to be present when I load the core, and throws even if another lib was already loaded in its place.

Also, the library that isn't listed remains unstripped and isn't automatically added to the package. I have to export unsigned apk from eclipse, add .so, sign, align and reinstall every time, which is bearable but far from practical.

Any suggestions on how to build the core binary without introducing a hardcoded dependency-by-module-name? Is there a civilized way to hook 'non-referenced' libraries up for packaging with the rest of the stuff?

---

Finally found the problem - had a mixed file with both neon and normal code built with .neon suffix. Apparently library can contain both NEON and plain-v7a code, a single file however can't - d32 instructions leak outside of neon execution paths and runtime linker does this:

```
D/dalvikvm(5323): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.my.app/lib/libapp.so 0x410b96e8
A/libc(5323): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x5c21ae92 (code=1)
D/dalvikvm(3908): GC_CONCURRENT freed 222K, 9% free 7010K/7687K, paused 38ms+2ms
I/DEBUG(91): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG(91): Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/ThinkPadTablet/Indigo:4.0.3/ThinkPadTablet_A400_03/0070_0132_ROW:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG(91): pid: 5323, tid: 5336  >>> com.my.app <<<
I/DEBUG(91): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 5c21ae96
I/DEBUG(91):  r0 5c51d250  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG(91):  r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG(91):  r8 00000000  r9 3f800000  10 3f800000  fp 00000000
I/DEBUG(91):  ip 00000000  sp 5bc1c9d8  lr 5bf7423d  pc 5c21ae96  cpsr 40000070
I/DEBUG(91):  d0  3ef99342e0ee5069  d1  4012d97c7f3321d2
I/DEBUG(91):  d2  3f985a30f4230d02  d3  3fa55553e1053a42
I/DEBUG(91):  d4  543f7d0ef4230d02  d5  41d50fdf43800000
I/DEBUG(91):  d6  0000000000000000  d7  42c8000041f00000
I/DEBUG(91):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(91):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(91):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(91):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG(91):  scr 80000012
I/DEBUG(91):          #00  pc 005fde96  /data/data/com.my.app/lib/libapp.so (_ZN4math7Matrix4C2Effffffffffffffff)

  5fde90:   eddd 0b0c   vldr    d16, [sp, #48]  ; 0x30
  5fde94:   eddd 1b0e   vldr    d17, [sp, #56]  ; 0x38
  5fde98:   f8cd 8028   str.w   r8, [sp, #40]   ; 0x28
```

Comment: No, the libraries I mentioned (libav, OpenH264, and the `hello-neon` example) all work fine with NEON on devices where it exists, and still working on Tegra2, all within the same build. You shouldn't build the non-NEON codepaths with vfpv3-d32, only with vfpv3-d16. So no code built with vfpv3-d32/NEON should ever be executed unless a runtime check detected it.

Comment: And can you give an example of such a runtime linker error that refuses to load such code? Because I have never seen/heard of such behaviour.

Comment: Also, how to build a library with these compiler flags enabled only for some files obviously depends on the library's build system. For Android.mk you can do it by making sure the optional codepaths are in separate files, and add .neon to the end of those filenames in LOCAL_SRC_FILES. For hand-written assembly you don't need any extra compiler flags at all, you only need them for inline assembly or intrinsics.

Comment: @mstorsjo That's exactly what I was doing - .neon suffix on files with neon function implementations, called from 'normal' functions. The runtime checks are there, but the code never had a chance to be executed in the first place, since the library would not load. My guess is that it chokes up not with neon instructions, linker apparently would have to let them through, but with d32 registers, which are neither supported by the device nor in the neon subset.

Comment: Please show me the errors from the linker - as I said, I'm pretty sure that you are seeing some unrelated issue which is leading you astray. The linker will not fail to load a binary even if it has got NEON instructions or using vfpv3-d32, but it will fail with a SIGILL when trying to run such an instruction.

Comment: @mstorsjo Apparently this a very obscured issue, as I wasn't able to find much on it. [There](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=366) is a bug from libtbb that was fixed by abandoning neon, [there](https://plus.google.com/+CyanogenMod/posts/8wcuSVkr7zR) is cyanogenmod dropping Tegra 2 support specifically, and there was a table of ARM CPUs somewhere showing very few of them lack d32 registers, which I cannot find now.

Comment: Yes, ARMv7 devices that don't support NEON also lack the d32 registers. The bug from libtbb that you linked clearly show a SIGILL, not a linker refusing to load the binary. I'm repeating my request, please show a log of your claimed linker refusing to load such a library. I'm saying that the linker absolutely will load the library, if not, you have done something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @mstorsjo After two days checking everything everywhere I'm too at least 'pretty sure', but I hope you are right, gonna triple-check next time I get my hands on that tablet.

Comment: Also, next time you get to try that tablet, doublecheck that the `hello-neon` sample works on it - I can guarantee that it loads and works fine, even though the binary contains NEON/vfpv3-d32 instructions.

Comment: @mstorsjo You was right. I had no idea the runtime linker could differentiate between kinds of code within library. This gonna make my life much easier, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's not the runtime linker that gives the error you had, it's the processor throwing a SIGILL. The runtime linker itself doesn't really care exactly what kind of instructions there are within the functions, as long as you don't try to execute them. But great to have this clarified and fixed properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to load one library or the other without having a dependency on the module name, it's probably easiest to avoid linking directly to that library, and just loading the right one at runtime and loading symbols from it dynamically using `dlsym`. If the library only has got a few functions/entry points, this shouldn't be too complicated. If, on the other hand, the library has got a very large interface (C++ libraries often tend to use lots of entry points, much harder to load with `dlsym`), that's much harder.

Technically, if this wasn't limited to android, you could have two different versions of the library with identical names in different directories, and load the right one beforehand.

But in principle you shouldn't necessarily need two different versions of the library. You wrote:

> but it turns out a native library cannot be both plain-v7a and NEON at the same time anyway, the runtime linker simply won't load such a library on some devices.

A library most certainly can contain both plain-v7a and NEON code, and should load on all armeabi-v7a devices - there are many such libraries out there. You just need to make sure that the common codepaths aren't built with NEON enabled, and that the internal NEON codepaths only are used after a runtime check. This requires that the library is designed with runtime-enabled SIMD-extensions in mind from the start, though - some libraries might be designed to decide on such things at compile time. And adding `-mfpu=neon` (or adding `.neon` to the filename in `Android.mk`) to generic, non-SIMD code doesn't really add much measurable performance boost to normal code; at worst it will just insert a few instructions occasionally which will stop the code from running on other devices, without actually helping performance much.

The `hello-neon` sample in the NDK is a trivial example on how to handle this. Actual real-world libraries that do this are libav and OpenH264, to mention just a few.

Comment: The problem is, I don't think I understand how to properly build the core without linking it against one of the library versions. And unreferenced libraries it seems are completely ignored when core is being built, even if I do import-module no .so is produced.

Comment: Alright dlsym seem to be the way to go. Hoped to have everything in a single project and avoid manual linking, that moodstock post made me think it is possible, but it looks like alternative library not going to link automatically anyway.